# Is it a bad idea to run a t-test when you have a lot of observations?

Tags: t-test

Was trying to run a 2-sample t-test on 2 populations.

My question is that if your two samples combined had a very large number of observations and since the standard error [sigma/sqrt(N)] would be very small, would it amplify a small difference between two means? And this could lead to the wrong conclusion of them being different?

I know that the formula I used for standard error is not accurate, just wanted to keep it simple to illustrate the point.

Comment: The standard error might be smaller but that's not a problem. No it won't lead to wrong conclusion.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of getting a lot of observations that you can resolve even small differences in the means?

Comment: What I mean is that would having such a small standard error lead me to believe that two groups are different.

For eg: Average test score of two age groups are 99.4 and 99.5. But standard error is very low, like 0.001, which would lead to a t-statistic of 100. Wouldn't that make me think there is a very marked difference between both age groups?

Comment: Tell us how many observations you do have, and how did you obtain them? The t-test supposes independent observations, and with very large sample sizes that starts (in practice) to be doubtful.

Comment: It sounds like you're worried not just about significance, but effect size (as well you should be). Here's a great article outlining the difference: [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3444174/](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3444174/)

Comment: This is a great example of exactly the issue you're worried about (statistically significant, but small effect size): [Does bacon cause cancer?](http://scienceblog.cancerresearchuk.org/2015/10/26/processed-meat-and-cancer-what-you-need-to-know/) You might remember it in the news a couple years ago. The short answer is that risk of cancer *does* significantly increase with consumption of processed meats, but the *size* of the increase is pretty small (although it is bigger than 0, which is what the significance test asks).

Comment: @RoseHartman thank you for providing the links, they are very relevant to what I was asking. So it seems like Cohen's d is a suggested measure of effect size. I don't know too much about it, but are there any other types of effect measures I should look for?

Comment: The user should know based on the problem being address what a difference worth detecting is.

Comment: @rayven1lk There are lots of kinds of measures for effect size, and you'll want different effect size estimates for different kinds of hypotheses and models. But cohen's d is definitely the standard one for independent samples t-tests, so that's what I'd recommend for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

No, as this confuses statistical power (ability to detect a true effect) with the size of the effect. The larger your sample size, all other things being equal, the more precision you have in your data, as expressed by the smaller standard error. This does not amplify the difference between the means, as that differences should converge on the true population difference. With a large sample, you are able to detect a small true difference in the means, but this is not an error or wrong conclusion. As a large t-value and hence a small p-value does not indicate a large effect, only high confidence that there is a true difference, of whatever size. Use the actual difference in the means (or an effect size such as Cohen's d, which is by the way unaffected by the sample size) to assess the whether the difference that is detected is meaningful in your context.